# facebook login redirect drupal for facebook module

Tags: users, redirection, social-network

I am using [Drupal for facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb/) module. I want to redirect user to specific URL, if he login from facebook ? Note: I am using [Login destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) for normal users and works fine for this.

Comment: any updates...?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal for facebook module has a sub module called "FB Rules Integration"
Enable it.

Then create a new rule:
give it a name, something like "after connecting facebook account".

add an action: page redirect
then enter where do you want to redirect to, something like ""

Here is an export of the rule which you can just import.

```
{ "rules_after_connecting_facebook_account" : {
    "LABEL" : "after connecting facebook account",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "Drupal for Facebook" ],
    "ON" : [ "fb_user_connected", "fb_user_login" ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "\u003Cfront\u003E" } } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use hook_fb, provided by drupal for facebook module like this:

```
function fb_example_fb($op, $data, &$return) {
  $fb_app = isset($data['fb_app']) ? $data['fb_app'] : NULL;
  $fb = isset($data['fb']) ? $data['fb'] : NULL;
  if ($op == FB_OP_AJAX_EVENT) {
    // We get FB_OP_AJAX_EVENT when fb.js calls us in reponse to a javascript event.

    if ($data['event_type'] == 'session_change') {
      // The user has clicked the connect button, or logged into/out-of
      // facebook in another browser window, then refreshed.
      if ($fbu = fb_facebook_user()) {
        // The user has connected (as opposed to logged out).  Let's redirect
        // them to our 'welcome' page.  Replace 'welcome' with the path you
        // really want.
        $url = url('welcome',
                   array('absolute' => TRUE, 'fb_canvas' => fb_is_canvas()));
        // We return javascript to be evaluated by fb.js.
        $return[] = 'FB_JS.reload("'. $url .'");';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This one worked for me.

Also you can check this [link](https://drupal.org/node/969242) for more informations.

Hope it helps someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

An easy option would be to use simple fb connect module. It has this feature out of the box. On the configuration page there is a form where you can add the (dynamic) path. The user will be redirected to this path when logging in with fb.